# how to use google cloud text to speech API? i contacted their support not of much help. any smart guy who can get me through this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created the credentials, but was not able to locate the product for end use. there was a page but we had to use code there some jason script may be. not the product they showed in the demo.

Comment: Read this link to help you create a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OP please edit your post accordingly. Help the community help you.